# Как передать параметры в collback функцию в async each?

Tags: node.js, express, асинхронность

Подскажите как результат передать в collback функцию

```js
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  var arr = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 2,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 3,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 4,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 5,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 6,
    b: 2
  }];
    var result = [];
    async.each(arr, function(file, callback) {
        console.log("file: " + file.a);
        result.push(file.a);
        console.log(result);
            callback();

    }, function(err){
        if( err ) {
            console.log('A file failed to process');
        } else {
            console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
        }
    });
  res.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```js
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  var arr = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 2,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 3,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 4,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 5,
    b: 2
  }, {
    a: 6,
    b: 2
  }];
  var result = [];
  async.map(arr, function(file, callback) {
    console.log("file: " + file.a);
    result.push(file.a);
    console.log(result);
    callback(null, relult);

  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('A file failed to process');
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
  res.end();
});
```

Comment: `async.map` и без этого в callback передаст готовый массив с результатами `iterator(item)`.